# Save data stored in variables, list and dict to csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I'm trying to create a csv file with my user information. I've maneged to create a csv file for my variables such as "name", "surname" and age, but I have also information stored in list and dict with an unknown length and I don't need to parse them right now (I'll do it in the future) so right now I'll be just fine being able to save all the list item separeted by a comma in a cell and the same goes for the dic, the data looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "myname",
    "surname": "mysurname",
    "subjectGender": "maschiocis",
    "age": "999",
    "list": [
        922,
        938,
        952],
    "dict:" [
    {
      one: 332,
      two: 395,
      three: 013,
      four: 953,
      five: 801,
      six: 924,
      seven: 905
    },
    {
        one: 192,
        two: 742,
        three: 113,
        four: 253,
        five: 881,
        six: 967,
        seven: 744
    },]
  }
```

This is the code I have till now:

**controllers/data.js**

```
exports.saveData = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const dataNew = new DataInfo({
      //info
      name: req.body.name,
      surname: req.body.surname,
      age: req.body.age,

      list: req.body.listone,
      dict: req.body.dictone,

      
    });
    console.log(dataNew);

    // SAVED DATA START

    const data = `
      name,surname,age
      ${req.body.name},${req.body.surname},${req.body.age}
     `;

    fs.writeFile("./data.csv", data, "utf-8", (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log("Data saved");
    });

    //SAVE DATA END

    const savedResult = await dataNew.save();
    console.log(savedResult);
    if (!savedResult) {
      res.status(500).json({ isError: true });
    }
    res.status(200).json({ isError: false });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(300).json({ isError: true });
  }
};
```

also is there a way to use ";" as delimiter instead of ","? since right now when I open it my data.csv file is all messed up.
Thank you all

Comment: i think CSV can also use ; seperator iirc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you need to convert an array or an object to a string, so you can save to the CSV. There's several ways of doing this, but a simple one is using `JSON.stringify`. To avoid problems you can enclose your CSV data in quotes and use semicolon instead of commas. Since JSON.stringify also uses double quotes, you need to escape then with an extra double quote.

```js
const list = [922, 938, 952],
 dict = [{one: 332, two: 395},{three: 013,four: 953}]

function convert(data) {
  return JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"/g, '""');
}

console.log(convert(list));
console.log(convert(dict));
```

Then use on your code like this:

```
const data = `
  name;surname;age;list;dict
  "${req.body.name}";"${req.body.surname}";"${req.body.age}";"${convert(req.body.list)}";"${convert(req.body.dict)}"
 `;
```